# I have text field on lightning web component but I want user to be allowed to put only numbers, please help

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have one field on lightning component which is text field but I want user to be allowed to put only number and incase of text it will throw error. Please help

Comment: Are you using a Lightning Web Component or an Aura component? It's not possible to tell. Are you open to validation rules or strictly client-side validation in your component?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] your question to include code snippets illustrating what you have done and where you are stuck. If you are using `lightning:input` or `lightning-input` for this text field, you should be able to simply set the required `type` to `number`, but exactly how depends on what you have done and whether it is Aura or LWC.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response, Its lwc and I cant use validation rule as its strictly client- side validation in component, so basically my text field will be placed in lwc component and I want only number to be allowed on this field Incase of text it should throw error. . can you please suggest a approach here.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Thank you for answering questions & giving additional information. Please edit your question to add that additional information & answers to questions in the comments - it makes it easier for someone reading this later to get all of the information instead of having to dig through comments. For more complicated questions, it also makes it easier to get help.

Answer (score 1):

`<lightning-input type="number">`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation